# Why is there no std::clear in c++11 standard library

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, containers, std

Since there are now generic iterator on c++ standard library like [`std::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), I am wondering why there is no `std::clear()` method to clear a container?

Answer (score 12):

The nice thing about `std::begin/end` is that it can be implemented for arrays.  However it can only be implemented as namespace scope functions for arrays.  Therefore in generic code it is nice to have `std::begin/end` so that the generic code doesn't have to decide whether it needs to use namespace scope or member functions when needing `begin/end`.

But I know of no such analogy for `std::clear`.  It can only be implemented for containers which have member `clear()`.  There is no dilemma for how to use it in generic code (at least not that I can think of).

Comment: Also I might be wrong about this, but I feel like half the reason they need `std::begin` and `std::end` is so arrays will work with range based for loops

Comment: @aaronman: Actually the range-based-for was rigged so that it will work even if `<iterator>` has not been included.

Comment: @aaronman: but if we had std::clear, wouldn't it be possible to implement a clear method for a old style C array for instance.

Comment: @KevinMOLCARD:  What would `clear(array)` do?  On containers a post-condition of `clear()` is that `empty() == true` (`size() == 0`).

Comment: @aaronman: you are right. TBH, your first answer did not convince me but now I think understand why there is no such std::clear. thanks again